# Difference between マネ and 行動

Tags: word-choice

Could you explain the difference between マネ and 行動 as in the following sentences:

> 安心したまえ　この男のリスクリターンの計算と‌自己保身に関してだけはなかなかのものだ‌
>   刑事罰に問われるような**マネ**だけは決してしない‌
>
> Don't worry about that.‌ This guy's ability to evaluate risk vs. return and his sense of self-preservation are quite something.‌ He wouldn't do anything that would get him charged with a crime.‌

> 自分の信念を持って**行動**しているに過ぎないわ。
>
> I'm just acting on my own beliefs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both マネ (真似) and 行動 can be translated to "act" or "behavior", but マネ is an accusatory and a little dirty expression, and it is always modified by an adjectival phrase such as ふざけた, 馬鹿な, こんな or ～ような. 行動 is relatively a stiff word suitable in academic contexts, and it is rarely used in slangy speech.

- 刑事罰に問われるような行動: OK
- 刑事罰に問われるようなマネ: OK (sounds more accusatory)
- 自分の信念を持って行動している: OK
- 自分の信念を持ってマネしている: Incorrect (マネ is not modified by an adjectival expression, and this "act" is used in a positive way)
- ナメた行動するんじゃねェ: Unnatural (mixture of slangy and formal words)
- ナメたマネするんじゃねェ: OK (see [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4144/5010))
- ヘビの行動を研究している学者: OK
- ヘビのマネを研究している学者: Incorrect